# SharedPreferences keep on returning default value

Tags: android

I would like to display the name and user type after registration and login. For this app, after a person registers, one is taken back to the log in screen. If the login is successful, the homepage activity will open.
I'm trying to send the name and user type value from registration to homepage but sharePreferences kept on returning the null value.
(Registration)

```
 //grab the user type to homepage
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.user_type_spinner);
    String userType = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 
     Registration.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("NAME", name.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("USER_TYPE", userType);
    editor.commit();
```

---

(Homepage)

```
    //Grab name and user type to show in homepage
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 
     Registration.MODE_PRIVATE);
    textUserType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textWelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //Get name and user type
    String prefName=preferences.getString("NAME", "");
    String prefUserName=preferences.getString("USER_TYPE", "");
    //display the view
   textName.setText("Hello " + prefName + "!");
   textWelcome.setText("Welcome");
    textUserType.setText("User type:" +prefUserName);
```

Comment: could you please provide your full code

Comment: Ruben's right, outside of you should define the "NAME" and "USER_TYPE" strings as static final Strings outside of that code, I don't see any issues with these snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the answer given by Haj Ali, it works....But I think that keeping an user and his password inside the sharedpreferences XML file is a **REALLY** bad practice since anyone can steal the file and obtain the credentials.

-> If your passing parameters from one activity to another, add the parameters to your intent.

-> If you're passing parameters from an activity to a fragment, add the parameters to a bundle, and then add the bundle to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow such a model:

Activity A:

```
           //inputs
           String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
           String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            //SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                    getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("email",email);
            editor.putString("password",password);
                 editor.commit();
```

Activity B:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.
                getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        email= sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
        password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
```